# A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-navigation'

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I Installed react native navigation V7.25.4,
now when I sync project in android studio I get error

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-navigation'.
> It is too late to set sourceCompatibility
  It has already been read to configure this project.
  Consider either moving this call to be during evaluation,
  or using the variant API.
```

I also have two error on build.gradle of react-native-navigation

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'json'
Cannot resolve symbol 'JsonSlurper'
```

this is  build.gradle of react-native-navigation:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestExceptionFormat

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

def safeExtGet(prop, fallback) {
    rootProject.ext.has(prop) ? rootProject.ext.get(prop) : fallback
}

def safeExtGetFallbackLowerBound(prop, fallback) {
    Math.max(safeExtGet(prop,fallback),fallback)
}

def DEFAULT_COMPILE_SDK_VERSION = 30
def DEFAULT_MIN_SDK_VERSION = 21
def DEFAULT_TARGET_SDK_VERSION = 30
def DEFAULT_KOTLIN_VERSION = "1.5.31"
def DEFAULT_KOTLIN_STDLIB = 'kotlin-stdlib-jdk8'
def kotlinVersion = safeExtGet("RNNKotlinVersion", DEFAULT_KOTLIN_VERSION)
def kotlinStdlib = safeExtGet('RNNKotlinStdlib',DEFAULT_KOTLIN_STDLIB )
def kotlinCoroutinesCore = safeExtGet('RNNKotlinCoroutinesCore', '1.5.2')
android {
    compileSdkVersion safeExtGetFallbackLowerBound('compileSdkVersion', DEFAULT_COMPILE_SDK_VERSION)

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion safeExtGetFallbackLowerBound('minSdkVersion', DEFAULT_MIN_SDK_VERSION)
        targetSdkVersion safeExtGetFallbackLowerBound('targetSdkVersion', DEFAULT_TARGET_SDK_VERSION)
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests.includeAndroidResources = true
        unitTests.all { t ->
            maxHeapSize = "4g"
            reports {
                html.enabled true
            }
            testLogging {
                events "PASSED", "SKIPPED", "FAILED"
                exceptionFormat TestExceptionFormat.FULL
                showExceptions true
                showCauses true
                showStackTraces true
            }
            afterSuite { desc, result ->
                if (!desc.parent) { // will match the outermost suite
                    def output = "      ${result.resultType} (${result.successfulTestCount} successes, ${result.failedTestCount} failures, ${result.skippedTestCount} skipped)     "
                    def repeatLength = output.length()
                    println '\n\n' + ('-' * repeatLength) + '\n' + output + '\n' + ('-' * repeatLength) + '\n'

                    println "see report at file://${t.reports.html.destination}/index.html"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    flavorDimensions "RNN.reactNativeVersion"
    productFlavors {
        reactNative51 {
            dimension "RNN.reactNativeVersion"
            buildConfigField("int", "REACT_NATVE_VERSION_MINOR", "51")
        }
        reactNative55 {
            dimension "RNN.reactNativeVersion"
            buildConfigField("int", "REACT_NATVE_VERSION_MINOR", "55")
        }
        reactNative56 {
            dimension "RNN.reactNativeVersion"
            buildConfigField("int", "REACT_NATVE_VERSION_MINOR", "56")
        }
        reactNative57 {
            dimension "RNN.reactNativeVersion"
            buildConfigField("int", "REACT_NATVE_VERSION_MINOR", "57")
        }
        reactNative57_5 {
            dimension "RNN.reactNativeVersion"
            buildConfigField("int", "REACT_NATVE_VERSION_MINOR", "57")
        }
        reactNative60 {
            dimension "RNN.reactNativeVersion"
            buildConfigField("int", "REACT_NATVE_VERSION_MINOR", "60")
        }
        reactNative62 {
            dimension "RNN.reactNativeVersion"
            buildConfigField("int", "REACT_NATVE_VERSION_MINOR", "62")
        }
        reactNative63 {
            dimension "RNN.reactNativeVersion"
            buildConfigField("int", "REACT_NATVE_VERSION_MINOR", "63")
        }
    }

    def flavor = resolveFlavor()
    variantFilter { variant ->
        def names = variant.flavors*.name
        if (!names.contains(flavor)) {
            setIgnore(true)
        }
    }
}

String resolveFlavor() {
    List reactNativeVersionComponents = reactNativeVersionComponents(findReactNativePackageJson())
    Integer reactNativeMinorComponent = reactNativeVersionComponents[1].toInteger()
    Integer reactNativePatchComponent = reactNativeVersionComponents[2].toInteger()

    if (reactNativeMinorComponent >= 63) {
        return "reactNative63"
    } else if (reactNativeMinorComponent >= 62) {
        return "reactNative62"
    } else if (reactNativeMinorComponent >= 60) {
        return "reactNative60"
    } else if (reactNativeMinorComponent >= 57 && reactNativePatchComponent >= 5) {
        return "reactNative57_5"
    } else if (reactNativeMinorComponent >= 57) {
        return "reactNative57"
    } else if (reactNativeMinorComponent >= 56) {
        return "reactNative56"
    } else if (reactNativeMinorComponent >= 55) {
        return "reactNative55"
    } else if (reactNativeMinorComponent >= 51) {
        return "reactNative51"
    }
}


Object findReactNativePackageJson() {
    def searchPath = 'node_modules/react-native/package.json'
    def projectDir = project.projectDir.toString() + '/'
    def rnPackageJsonFile = new File(projectDir + searchPath)
    while (!rnPackageJsonFile.exists()) {
        searchPath = '../' + searchPath
        rnPackageJsonFile = new File(projectDir + searchPath)
    }
    return rnPackageJsonFile
}

List reactNativeVersionComponents(rnPackageJsonFile) {
    def packageSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
    def reactNativePackageJson = packageSlurper.parseText(rnPackageJsonFile.text)
    def reactNativeVersion = reactNativePackageJson.version

    return reactNativeVersion.tokenize('-')[0].tokenize('.')
}

allprojects { p ->
    p.afterEvaluate {
        p.android.compileOptions.sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        p.android.compileOptions.targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    p.repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-json:3.0.9' // add manual
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:$kotlinStdlib:$kotlinVersion"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$kotlinCoroutinesCore"
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4"

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha03'

    implementation 'com.github.wix-playground:ahbottomnavigation:3.3.0'
//    implementation project(':AHBottomNavigation')
    implementation 'com.github.wix-playground:reflow-animator:1.0.6'
    implementation 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'

    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'

    if("Playground".toLowerCase() == rootProject.name.toLowerCase()){
        // tests only for our playground
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
        testImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:4.7.2"
        testImplementation 'org.assertj:assertj-core:3.11.1'
        testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:4.0.0'
        testImplementation 'com.squareup.assertj:assertj-android:1.2.0'
        testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:3.4.0'
        testImplementation "org.mockito.kotlin:mockito-kotlin:4.0.0"
        testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:$kotlinVersion"
    }
}
```

my android studio version : 2021.1.1 patch2.

classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.31"

classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2')

Answer (score 0):

This is the same issue as [It is too late to set sourceCompatibility :react-native-navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74941590/it-is-too-late-to-set-sourcecompatibility-react-native-navigation).

It is caused due to an issue with pre-7.26 versions of React Native Navigation's `app/build.gradle` configuration.

The solution is to upgrade or manually fix the broken configuration (https://stackoverflow.com/a/77923298/4821759)